# Barebones list for ParanoidAndroid (stock apps that can be removed safely)

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms

Which apps are safe to uninstall in ParanoidAndroid?

Do we have a [barebones list](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Barebones#CM-10.1_App_list_.28WIP.29) like what CM has?
Can someone share a similar list/link.

Comment: Why not use a Vanilla ROM, AOSP? About stripped down as you can get. Swap out open source apps for stock ones if preferred.

Comment: Wil try these out. But still would to have that list. I like PA better than anything else.

Comment: I just don't think there is definitive list. You could flash Paranoid then ONE BY ONE delete apps, making sure there isnt any incompatibilities. Once you complete your process, make a backup so you can restore the ROM with your changes anytime needed.

Comment: Could not find a similar list after searching endlessly. I used the CM list itself, along with http://blog.burrowsapps.com/2014/03/what-android-apps-are-safe-to-remove.html to disable apps. Thanks for the tip. Will definitely create a backup using Titanium.